# Best Practice for delivering 10 base 64 images

Tags: php, mysql, cordova, base64

I am developing a phonegap app, one part of the app is about 10 images that are base64 encoded and downloaded about once per week per user(100 users now, hopefully growing alot)
My server is slow, which i am also working on, so delivery of these images is slow.
My question is:
Would it be faster, php and server wise, to generate and save these base64 images to a db once and fetch the images from the db on request OR base64 encode the image every time the image is requested?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would *definitely* be faster to base64 encode the images and store the encoding.

This is a classic memory vs. speed tradeoff, you can pay a lower computation cost, for a higher memory cost. In this case, that means storing *more* data (<strike>8/7</strike> 8/6 more if you just keep the encoded version, and a little more than 2x if you keep the original too).

The best thing you could do is keep the images in memory, since this would avoid the cost of accessing the disk. You can do this with [shared memory functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php), or by abusing the session variables and assigning a fixed session id to retrieve content.

Comment: Base 64 is 8/6 of the original data size as it maps 6 bits to 8 bits (not 8/7)

Comment: Or "just memcached" -- although the original approach and solutions should be benchmarked. base64 is a *fast* algorithm, so I believe the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the details of your app, it seems to me that having a db for just 10 images is overkill. The added overhead of running the db on your slow server will probably kill any benefits you may get from saving on base64 encoding.

I would store the base64 encoded images as files instead of a db, so that they can be served directly to the clients by your web server.

I would also make sure you can deliver data gzip compressed if the client can handle it, since base64 data compresses really well. This will reduce the traffic to your server considerably. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression).

Comment: +1 for suggesting using the FS (and letting the server do it's thing): in this case though, the actual image would be sent (not the base64 which is used for sending the image embedded in the ML).

Answer (score 1):

You'll most likely be bandwidth-bound before your server become processor bound. My thoughts:

- Don't send base64-encoded images. Instead, send properly compressed binary data.
- Don't have the client update unless it needs to (i.e. don't grab the image if there's no newer image to grab). Use 304 headers and related to keep track.
- Once things start to hit hard, use memcache/Redis instead of a database to store the "pre-digested" image data.

Comment: +1 I'm a fan of actually *using* the HTTP protocol. There are also ETags, which could be useful here.